# Can you remove NetSuite Bundles after installation

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am working on a NetSuite instance that had custom(contractor/SuiteScript) work installed via a bundle, but it is not a third party product but made for this system. Now there are 2 listings in the dropdown for each file. In other words, if I am adding a file as a library, it shows up twice and I don't know which reference is the correct one to choose. I used search to find the duplicate file name is in the bundle install. Can I safely remove or delete the bundle? thanks any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot typically remove individual files from a bundle. If you do not need the functionality of the bundle anymore than you can remove it at your discretion by going to `Customization>SuiteBundler>Search & Install Bundles>List`, then under the action icon click 'Uninstall'.

I wouldn't try to delete a script library from a bundle folder. Even if you are uploading an identical library there may be references in the bundle scripts to the original library that will be broken when if you delete it.

If you are wondering which one you are selecting from the drop down one thing you could do is figure out the internal id of your library file then run a search on your script file that pulls in the library file id's and make sure that they match.

Comment: Ok, great thanks that is what I was looking for. As long as I can figure out which one it is pointing at. Thanks again!